# ValueError: The initializer passed is not valid

Tags: tensorflow2.0, python-3.7

ret = tf.compat.v1.get_variable(name=name, dtype=dtype, shape=shape,
initializer=GlorotNormal(),trainable=trainable)

ValueError: ValueError: The initializer passed is not valid. It should be a callable with no arguments and the shape should not be provided or an instance of `tf.keras.initializers.*' and` shape` should be fully defined.

I was write parameters like seed and shape, but ValueError is the same.
GlorotNormal(seed=None, shape=shape)